# Why does SGD converge for optimizing an expectation if expected update equals the actual gradient?

Tags: machine-learning, gradient-descent, reinforcement-learning, multiarmed-bandit

When optimizing an expected value, why is it true that stochastic updates will converge as long as the expected value of the update is equal to the corresponding gradient of the expected value?

For example, I see this fact used in the proof of the Gradient Bandit Algorithm in Section 2.8 of the Reinforcement Learning book by Sutton & Barto: http://people.inf.elte.hu/lorincz/Files/RL_2006/SuttonBook.pdf

I also see this fact put to use in this paper by Sutton et al: https://nips.cc/Conferences/2008/Schedule?showEvent=1346

I would appreciate if anyone could provide a proof, outline of a proof, or link to a proof of this fact.

UPDATE: I’ve found this is due to Robbins-Monro, which provides a stochastic approximation technique for finding zeros of a function when only a fuzzy version of the function is available. In this case that function is the gradient of the objective function, which also happens to be an expectation.

Comment: The convergence criteria is more than just that the expected value of the update is equal to the gradient of the expected value.  Since most SG techniques use fixed step sizes (as contrasted to a line search in the direction of the gradient, for example), it's also necessary that the step sizes go to 0 as the number of iterations increases.  However, in order to ensure that you can get to the actual target no matter where you start, the sum of the step sizes has to go to $\infty$ as the number of iterations increases.

Comment: Thanks! I believe this criterion was also outlined in the original Robbins-Monro paper.

Comment: Right.  I was really meaning to expand on your initial question by pointing out to the unwary reader (of whom there may well be none on this site) that the condition in the question isn't a sufficient condition for convergence.